# Greatly fruitful in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, adjective, cibus

I lack ample knowledge of Latin to piece together a proper equivalent phrase of the following: "Greatly fruitful," or "Great bounty"; in the context of referring to a food being very nutritious.

Here's what I've came up with; are these accurate?

> Magnus frux
>   Frux magnus

Comment: Welcome! I suggest taking a look at some [online dictionaries](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) and trying to find good words. For example, you can check if *magnus* and *frux* mean the thing you want. We can maybe suggest some words and help combine the words together, but your input helps us help you.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the previous suggestions, the first word that came to my mind was [*almus, -a, -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dalmus), which Lewis and Short glosses as:

> **nourishing, affording nourishment**, cherishing (poet. epithet of Ceres, Venus, and other patron deities of the earth, of light, day, wine, etc.; cf. Bentl. ad Hor. S. 2, 4, 13).—Hence, genial, restoring, reviving, kind, propitious, indulgent, **bountiful**, etc.

It's used, for instance, to describe *vites* (vines):

> Si deerunt, rarum pecorique et vitibus almis
>   aptius uber erit (Verg. G. 2, 233)

Other complementary words are [*uber, -is*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=uber&la=la&can=uber0&prior=aptius&d=Perseus:text:1999.02.0059:book=2:card=226&i=1#lexicon), which means "full, fruitful, fertile, abundant, plentiful, copious, productive," or [*fecundus, -a, -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfecundus), though these words are perhaps more appropriate in the context of living things than of food.

Comment: almus, uber, fecundus seem to me to describe only the source (e.g. ager) or provider (e.g. Ceres) of the fructus (or fruges — the sing. frux is not often seen). I think we need a more precise input from the questioner — does he want to describe the source, or the product?

Comment: @TomCotton Yeah, I can see that, but then again it's the *tree*, not the *fruit*, that is *fruitful* :)

Comment: I could suggest that he has strawberries in mind! We really ought to have a bit more information from him.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use single words of the intended meaning when they are available, as in this case, rather than invent phrases.

*fructuosus* means actually yielding plentiful fruit.

*frugifer* simply means yielding fruit, its superlative *frugiferrimus* being virtually the same as *fructuosus*.

'Very nourishing' is expressed by something like *maximi alimenti*, (roughly) 'of greatest alimentary value'.

Comment: I can't find any occurrences of *frugerrimus* as the superlative...do you have any examples?

Comment: Thanks — it should, of course, be frugiferrimus, formed regularly as in celer, celerrimus.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for an adjective for **greatly fruitful**, but then you also mention the noun phrase, **great bounty**, and the Latin noun, ***frux***.

> Fruitfulness, bounty and being filled with goodness are all part of
>   the meaning of the **Cornu Copiae**,  the horn of the goddess, Copia;
>   also called the **Horn of Plenty** or **cornucopia** in English. 
>   Perhaps, this answer is obvious and overused in our culture, however.

Other goddesses like *Fortuna* and *Pax* are depicted holding the ***Cornu Copiae***.  Here you can see a statue of **Tyche** (Greek **Τύχη**), the counterpart of the Roman goddess, Fortuna, holding the horn of plenty:

[image: Source: http://www.maicar.com/GML/000Images/tim/tyche2132.jpg]

**Cornu Copiae** corresponds to the Greek  **Κέρας Ἀμαλθείας**, the **horn of Amalthea** (Greek: Αμαλθεια), the goat who fostered and nursed Zeus.  He broke off one of her horns and the story goes that he then promised to fill it with good things to repair his mistake.

Lewis and Short gives explanation and ancient sources under the entry for ***[cornu, cornus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcornu)***- the horn of an animal:

> **Cornu Copiae** (less correctly, but freq. in late Lat., as one word,
>   **Cornūcōpĭae** , and twice **Cornūcōpĭa , ae, f.**, Amm. 22, 9, 1; 25, 2, 3),
>   acc. to the fable, the horn of the goat Amalthea placed in heaven,
>   Greek Κέρας Ἀμαλθείας (v. Amalthea), **the emblem of fruitfulness and
>   abundance**, Plaut. Ps. 2, 3, 5; Gell. 14, 6, 2; cf. Hor. C. 1, 17, 16;
>   id. C. S. 60; id. Ep. 1, 12, 29; Ov. M. 9, 88.

Addendum:  ***Tellus Mater*** or ***Terra Mater***, Mother Earth, is also depicted holding the Cornu Copiae on her lap with children by her side.

[image: Tellus Mater / Gaia]

Comment: Good suggestion! Do you want to include the picture here in the answer or just give the link?

Comment: Oh, I am not good with technology.  If you know how to put the picture in, please edit it for me!

Comment: I put it in. Feel free to re-edit to format to your liking!

Comment: Gratias tibi ago, @JoonasIlmavirta! I also figured out how to add a photo. I just needed a little push in that direction. I am interested in the connection between Tellus Mater and Alma Mater (with regard to education) and may post a question about that.